# Removing auto click from links with cursor at the end of the link in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I have a editText which can accept links. I have set autoLink to true. I need to click at the end of the link and start typing another word or any text. But the problem is that, when I click at the end of the link, it redirects me to the specific link, but I need to type from there and thus I am not able to type.

My fragment code:

```
binding?.notepadPage?.apply {
            setBackPressInterceptor { onFragmentBackPressed() }
            movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
            requestFocus()
        }
```

```
binding?.notepadPage?.let {
            EditTextLinksHelper(it)
            val isSharedNote = (myFragmentID == 2)
            CharLimitApplier(it, isSharedNote) { charCountInt: Int, charCountWithLimit: String? ->
                binding?.charCount?.text = charCountWithLimit
                val isPremium = DefaultPrefSettings.getInstance().isPremium
                isOtherPremiumLocal.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { isOtherPremium_ ->
                    isOtherPremium_?.let { isOtherPremium ->
                        if (isPremium || isOtherPremium) {
                            binding?.typingDisableSoon?.visibility = View.GONE
                        } else {
                            val charCountPercent = (0.9 * Constants.CHAR_COUNT_LIMIT_FREE_PLAN)
                            if (charCountInt < charCountPercent) {
                                binding?.typingDisableSoon?.visibility = View.GONE
                            } else {
                                binding?.typingDisableSoon?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                binding?.typingDisableSoon?.text =
                                    "Warning: You will soon reach the typing limit. You will not be able to type. Upgrade to our premium plan for unlimited typing."
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The EditTextLinksHelper:

```
class EditTextLinksHelper(
    editText: EditText
) {

    private val textWatcher = object : TextWatcher {

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            Linkify.addLinks(editText, Linkify.WEB_URLS)
        }
    }

    init {
        editText.apply {
            linksClickable = true
            autoLinkMask = Linkify.WEB_URLS
            movementMethod = CustomLinkMovementMethod.instance
            addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        }
    }


    class CustomLinkMovementMethod : ArrowKeyMovementMethod() {
        override fun onTouchEvent(
            widget: TextView,
            buffer: Spannable,
            event: MotionEvent
        ): Boolean {
            val action = event.action
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                val x = event.x - widget.totalPaddingLeft + widget.scrollX
                val y = event.y.toInt() - widget.totalPaddingTop + widget.scrollY
                val line = widget.layout.getLineForVertical(y)
                val off = widget.layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x)
                val link = buffer.getSpans(off, off, ClickableSpan::class.java)
                if (link.isNotEmpty()) {
                    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        link[0].onClick(widget)
                    } else {
                        Selection.setSelection(
                            buffer, buffer.getSpanStart(link[0]), buffer.getSpanEnd(link[0])
                        )
                    }
                    return true
                }
            }
            return super.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event)
        }

        companion object {
            private var sInstance: CustomLinkMovementMethod? = null
            val instance: MovementMethod?
                get() {
                    if (sInstance == null) {
                        sInstance = CustomLinkMovementMethod()
                    }
                    return sInstance
                }
        }
    }
}
```

My xml:

```
 <pacakage_name.view.BackInterceptorEditText
                android:id="@+id/notepadPage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/whoIsTyping"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:autoLink="web|email"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="top|start"
                android:lines="10"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textColorHint="#636363"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />
```

Comment: Resolved by overriding gesture detector and onTouch of editText view.